# What is the simplest way to keep query parameters in AngularJS when changing views?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a simple way to keep the query parameters when linking between views i Angular?

When I use ngHref, the query parameters are lost:

```
<a ng-href='OtherPage'>Other page</a>
```

I navigate from this url `http://localhost/Page.html#/?stat=77698382`, to this:   `http://localhost/Page.html#/OtherPage`.

This solution works, but it requires a function with an explicit redirect:

```
<a ng-click='redirectToOtherPage()'>Other page</a> 

$scope.redirectToOrderListPage = function() {
    $location.path('OtherPage');
};
```

Is there a more declarative way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those two are slightly different from one another. I think the code you're looking for is:

```
<a ng-href='#/OtherPage'>Other page</a>
```

`http://localhost/Page.html#/?stat=77698382` seems off.

You need to put your querystrings before the hash tag like so:

```
http://localhost/Page.html?stat=77698382#/
```

Then as you navigate around your app, the queryString will not be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. I've also tried '#OtherPage'. I have added examples of the url's in the question... in case it might make things clearer.

Comment: Yes, please give an example of the url you have

Comment: Thanks, that solves the redirect issue. But it introduces a second  problem: Angular doesn't recognize the query string anymore:
$location.search('stat') == undefined. 

On the other hand, $window.location.search returns the query string as text. And using sugarjs, I can simply write Object.fromQueryString($window.location.search).stat to get the query parameter.

Comment: Angular never recognized query strings. It only recognized hash tags, you just happened to put the stat behind the hash tag. Urls have always been built (even without angular) with URL?QUERY_STRING#HASH_TAGS

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue. I had to maintain querystring across multiple views. And, i also had to check on $$hash while maintaining the querystring. In my case, I should move the $$hash value only in the portfolio view. I hope this helps.

```
var onRouteChangeOff = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);
function routeChange(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
  onRouteChangeOff();
  if (oldUrl.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
    var queryString =  oldUrl.split('?')[1];
    queryString = queryString.split('#')[0];
    newUrl = $location.$$path + '?' + queryString;
    if($location.$$path === '/portfolio')
    {
      newUrl += '#' + $location.$$hash
    }
    $location.url(newUrl);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  return;
}
```

If you are only looking to maintain querystring across views where you do not have any $$hash value, then the following code would be fine.

```
var onRouteChangeOff = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', routeChange);
function routeChange(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
  onRouteChangeOff();
  if (oldUrl.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
    var queryString =  oldUrl.split('?')[1];        
    newUrl = $location.$$path + '?' + queryString;        
    $location.url(newUrl);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code in TypeScript, Angular 1.
It parses the old query parameters and merges them into the new ones.
(Based on Pankaj's answer.)

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', (event:IAngularEvent, newUrl:string, oldUrl:string) => {

    let oldPath = oldUrl.replace(/^([^?#])+/, '$1');
    if (oldUrl.indexOf('?') >= 0 && oldPath !== $location.path()) {
      let queryString =  oldUrl.split('?')[1];
      if (queryString.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
        queryString = queryString.split('#')[0];
      }

      let oldParamStrings:string[] = queryString.split('&');
      let oldParams:{[key:string]:string} = {};
      oldParamStrings.forEach((oldParamString:string) => {
        let keyValue:string[] = oldParamString.split('=');
        oldParams[decodeURIComponent(keyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]);
      });

      let newParams = $location.search();
      if (!angular.equals(newParams, oldParams)) {
        angular.merge(newParams, oldParams);
        $location.search(newParams);
        return;
      }
    }

    // ANY OTHER CODE
    //////
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I currently attach `$location` service to the scope and use ng-click to navigate, e.g. `ng-click="$location.path('/target')"`.

Any query parameters will not be replaced.

Comment: I know this is not the prettiest way to do this, and I would do it differently now. But it works, so is something being pretty or not a reason to downvote?